# Problem while trying installing flask on windows (ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, flask

I am trying to install flask on my machine. I used both commands:

```
pip install flask
```

and

```
python3 -m pip install flask
```

What i get is the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                         
command: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python3.exe'
-u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x8pjl3ae\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x8pjl3ae\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qb6gobj5\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile                                                                                   cwd: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x8pjl3ae\MarkupSafe\  
Complete output (23 lines):                                            
running install                                                        
running build                                                          
running build_py                                                       
creating build                                                         
creating build\lib.win32-3.8                                           
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe                                
copying src\markupsafe\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe    
copying src\markupsafe\_constants.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe 
copying src\markupsafe\_native.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe    
copying src\markupsafe\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe   
running egg_info                                                       
writing src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO                               
writing dependency_links to src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt                           writing top-level names to src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt       
reading manifest file 'src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'            
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'                                
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'        
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution                                writing manifest file 'src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'                    
copying src\markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe   
running build_ext                                                      
building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension                              
error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'         
----------------------------------------                                                                            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python3.exe'
-u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x8pjl3ae\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x8pjl3ae\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qb6gobj5\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried doing this in a default folder that i created.

When trying a different approach (maybe) while following the installation instructions
[here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/#installation) i could not access the virtual environment like they suggested.

When typing

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

I get:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

When i check the Script folder, there is no activate file.
What should i do?

Comment: you install python only for your user account? I think you should reinstall python. I don't know why flask should need a Microsoft SDK.

Comment: I have installed once python 2.7 and it's path variable was under the system variables. When i installed python 3.8 it's path variable was under the user variables. I switch the variables so 2.7 will be in the user and 3.8 will be in the system. i still get the error after the changes.

Comment: Fix your environment.  `python -m venv .venv; .venv/Scripts/python -m pip install flask` (from powershell).  If this works, it's not related to your installs, but a broken PATH

Comment: Do i need the dot(.) before the venv in windows?
`python -m venv venv` gets me the following:
**Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**.
For the second command i get an error that says:
**No module named pip**